# WSO2AM gateway clustering issue

Tags: jmeter, distributed, wso2-api-manager

WSO2AM version : 1.10.0

i setup API manager after reviewing deployment pattern document.(https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/API+Manager+Deployment+Patterns)

i using L4 for LB.

i tested failover(gateway worker count 3 -> 2)
The result is strange.

TPS is close to zero for 5sec since one gateway worker process kill.

Why does this result?

Answer (score 0):

What is ur L4 dispatch policy ?
Does L4 set session sticky ?

Comment: L4 set round robin

Comment: It seems that the request has dispatched  to dead gateway node before L4 LB remove the dead node.